# c# format price to database with variant decimal places

Tags: c#

I need a function to retrieve the price well formated to be inserted into database. The database only accepts dot as decimal separator and cannot have thousands separator.

```
1,000.25 -> is not valid
1000.25  -> is valid
1000,25  -> is valid (but will be converted ',' to '.')
```

However not always the columns have 2 decimal places, some columns can have 5 decimal places.

```
public static double MoneyToDatabase(string value, int decimal_places)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) == true)
        return 0.00;

    value = value.Replace(",", "."); // converts the comma into dot

    string cardinal = "##";

    if(decimal_places > 2)
        for(int i = 3; i <= decimal_places; i++)
            cardinal += "#";

    return Convert.ToDouble(string.Format("{0:0." + cardinal + "}", value));
}
```

Problems and questions I'm facing:

1. Is there any way (in Linq or something) - besides loop - to add the remaining #?
2. `MoneyToDatabase("15,00", 2)` returns 1500, should return 15.00
3. `MoneyToDatabase("15,00", 5)` returns 1500, should return 15.00000
4. I have no clue what `'0:'` means

Comment: Did you ever try to use Double.TryParse instead?

Comment: I just gave a try and while debugging I saw that when converting (either with `Double.TryParse` or `Convert.ToDouble`) it automatically sets `15.00` as `1500.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

The actual problem was the CultureInfo and I found out I can use "F2", "F3" and that will retrieve the decimal places as I want.

```
public static string MoneyToDatabase(string value, int decimal_places)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) == true)
        return "0.00";

    value = value.Replace(",", ".");

    string format = "F" + decimal_places;

    double valueAsDouble;
    double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out valueAsDouble);

    // It sets again a comma in the string and must be replaced
    return valueAsDouble.ToString(format).Replace(",", ".");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use converts like below:

```
float.Parse("1,000.25", NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
float.Parse("1000.25", NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
1000,25  you can replace it ;).
```

Note that if you use different cultures do that with invariant cultures.

Comment: That doesn't work, because: 1.  `float v = float.Parse(value, NumberStyles.AllowThousands);` returns `1500.0` and 2. how do I set 5 decimal places, for example?